# What is the kinetic energy of a sphere rotating about a point and rolling without slipping on ground?

Tags: energy, rotational-kinematics

Some books say it is (1/2)I(orbital)w^2 + (1/2)I(spin)w'^2

But I don't find their derivation anywhere. [image]

The above picture says it is the answer but according to me...
[image]

This should be the answer. ( please only consider the last 4 lines.)

Please explain which is the right answer and why.

Comment: Hello! It is [preferable](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/10563/) to type out images of text; for formulae, one can use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/). Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Kinetic energy is equal to $mv_{cm}^2/2 + I \omega_0^2/2$ only for fixed axis rotation. Your example is not a fixed axis rotation because the axis OP is rotating. The general formula is
$$\textrm{KE} = \frac{1}{2}mv_{cm}^2 + \frac{1}{2}I_1 \omega_1^2 + \frac{1}{2}I_2 \omega_2^2 + \frac{1}{2}I_3 \omega_3^2$$
where the moments of inertia and angular velocity are in a coordinate system that coincides with the principle axes. If you want to see a derivation of this, then I refer you to chapter 8 of An Introduction to Mechanics by Kleppner and Kolankow. Anyways, applying this to your problem
$$\textrm{KE} = \frac{1}{2}mv_{cm}^2 + \frac{1}{2}I\omega_{orb}^2 + \frac{1}{2}I \omega_{s}^2$$
$$=\frac{1}{2}\left( mR^2 + I \right) \left( \frac{v_{cm}}{R} \right)^2 + \frac{1}{2}I \omega_s^2$$
$$ = \frac{1}{2} I_{orb} \omega_{orb}^2 + \frac{1}{2} I_s \omega_s^2$$
So the solution in the first pic is correct.